# Delete current row vba

Tags: vba, excel

**Problem:**

I need to drop rows that are not in my conditions.

**Code:**

Assume that all the values are initialized.

```
For ind = 2 To lrow
    reportProcess = Trim(LTrim(RTrim(ws.Range("G" & ind).Text)))
    If reportProcess = "Fulfillment - H/W Direct Customers (Operational)" Or reportProcess = "Revenue - Hardware" Then
        brand = "HW"
    ElseIf reportProcess = "Revenue - Software" Then
        ' ~~ Check Control Point Number
        subReportProcess = Mid(ws.Range("I" & ind).Text, 12, 3)
        If subReportProcess = "201" Or subReportProcess = "202" Or subReportProcess = "203" Or subReportProcess = "204" Or subReportProcess = "205" Then
             brand = "PBS"
        Else
             brand = "SWG"
        End If
    ElseIf reportProcess = "Revenue - GBS" Or reportProcess = "Revenue - GTS IS" Or reportProcess = "Fulfillment - Services(Operational)" Then
        brand = "PBS"
    ElseIf reportProcess = "Revenue - TSS" Then
        brand = "TSS"
    ElseIf reportProcess = "Accounts Receivable" Or reportProcess = "IBM Credit LLC - Accounts Receivable" Then
        brand = "AR"
    End If

    country = Trim(LTrim(RTrim(ws.Range("V" & ind).Text)))
    If country = "Taiwan" Then
        geo = "Taiwan"
    ElseIf country = "India" Then
        geo = "India"
    ElseIf country = "New Zealand" Or country = "Australia" Then
        geo = "ANZ"
    ElseIf country = "Hong Kong" Then
        geo = "Hong Kong"
    ElseIf country = "Philippines" Or country = "Malaysia" Or country = "Singapore" Or country = "Thailand" Or country = "Vietnam" Or country = "Indonesia" Then
        geo = "ASEAN"
    Else
    ' ~~ INSERT DELETE ROW HERE
    End If
    ws.Range("B" & ind) = geo
    ws.Range("A" & ind) = brand 
Next ind
```

**What I tried:**

`ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete` - but this deletes all the rows

`Selection.EntireRow.Delete` - same result as above

How can I use the loop to delete specific row number?

Comment: which row do you want to delete ?

Comment: @RachelChia the current one in the loop so if `ind = 2` and if the conditions does not match, delete it.

Comment: you want to delete the whole second row or first column second row? Don't really get what you want but if you want to delete specific row example: ws.Range("A" & ind).Delete or for entire row :Rows(ind).EntireRow.Delete

Comment: @RachelChia the whole row that does not match in my conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to iterate over the list from the last row to the first row.  If you do not that you will skip the next row after the deleted row.  Note: this also applies to removing items from listboxes, comboboxes and collections.

```
For ind = lrow To 2 Step -1
    reportProcess = Trim(LTrim(RTrim(ws.Range("G" & ind).Text)))
    If reportProcess = "Fulfillment - H/W Direct Customers (Operational)" Or reportProcess = "Revenue - Hardware" Then
        brand = "HW"
    ElseIf reportProcess = "Revenue - Software" Then
        ' ~~ Check Control Point Number
        subReportProcess = Mid(ws.Range("I" & ind).Text, 12, 3)
        If subReportProcess = "201" Or subReportProcess = "202" Or subReportProcess = "203" Or subReportProcess = "204" Or subReportProcess = "205" Then
            brand = "PBS"
        Else
            brand = "SWG"
        End If
    ElseIf reportProcess = "Revenue - GBS" Or reportProcess = "Revenue - GTS IS" Or reportProcess = "Fulfillment - Services(Operational)" Then
        brand = "PBS"
    ElseIf reportProcess = "Revenue - TSS" Then
        brand = "TSS"
    ElseIf reportProcess = "Accounts Receivable" Or reportProcess = "IBM Credit LLC - Accounts Receivable" Then
        brand = "AR"
    End If

    country = Trim(LTrim(RTrim(ws.Range("V" & ind).Text)))
    If country = "Taiwan" Then
        geo = "Taiwan"
    ElseIf country = "India" Then
        geo = "India"
    ElseIf country = "New Zealand" Or country = "Australia" Then
        geo = "ANZ"
    ElseIf country = "Hong Kong" Then
        geo = "Hong Kong"
    ElseIf country = "Philippines" Or country = "Malaysia" Or country = "Singapore" Or country = "Thailand" Or country = "Vietnam" Or country = "Indonesia" Then
        geo = "ASEAN"
    Else
        ' ~~ INSERT DELETE ROW HERE
        ws.Rows(ind).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
    ws.Range("B" & ind) = geo
    ws.Range("A" & ind) = brand
Next ind
```

---

I refactored the OP's code per @ShaiRado advice.

```
For ind = lrow To 2 Step -1
    reportProcess = Trim(LTrim(RTrim(ws.Range("G" & ind).Text)))
    Select Case reportProcess
    Case "Fulfillment - H/W Direct Customers (Operational)", "Revenue - Hardware"
        brand = "HW"
    Case "Revenue - Software"
        ' ~~ Check Control Point Number
        subReportProcess = Mid(ws.Range("I" & ind).Text, 12, 3)
        If subReportProcess = "201" Or subReportProcess = "202" Or subReportProcess = "203" Or subReportProcess = "204" Or subReportProcess = "205" Then
            brand = "PBS"
        Else
            brand = "SWG"
        End If
    Case "Revenue - GBS", "Revenue - GTS IS", "Fulfillment - Services(Operational)"
        brand = "PBS"
    Case "Revenue - TSS"
        brand = "TSS"
    Case "Accounts Receivable", "IBM Credit LLC - Accounts Receivable"
        brand = "AR"
    End Select

    country = Trim(LTrim(RTrim(ws.Range("V" & ind).Text)))
    Select Case country
    Case "Taiwan"
        geo = "Taiwan"
    Case "India"
        geo = "India"
    Case "New Zealand", "Australia"
        geo = "ANZ"
    Case "Hong Kong"
        geo = "Hong Kong"
    Case "Philippines", "Malaysia", "Singapore", "Thailand", "Vietnam", "Indonesia"
        geo = "ASEAN"
    Case Else
        ' ~~ INSERT DELETE ROW HERE
        ws.Rows(ind).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End Select

    ws.Range("B" & ind) = geo
    ws.Range("A" & ind) = brand
Next ind
```

Comment: Ohh I see, so that's why `Rows(ind).EntireRow.Delete` will not work. Thanks! This solved my problem :)

Comment: @Thomas Inzina  welcome back :) However, you're better than this, this code is "Screaming" for an upgrade to `Select Case` (instead of this messy `If`s and `Or` ).

Comment: @ShaiRado lol..you're right.  I should have either refactored it using the `Select Case` or just showed the modifications.  Code Updated. Thanks again

Comment: I forgot that `Case` exists in VBA lol. I'm a VBA newbieee :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
For ind = lrow To 2 Step -1
ws.Range("G" & ind).select
reportProcess = Trim(LTrim(RTrim(ws.Range("G" & ind).Text)))
If reportProcess = "Fulfillment - H/W Direct Customers (Operational)" Or reportProcess = "Revenue - Hardware" Then
    brand = "HW"
ElseIf reportProcess = "Revenue - Software" Then
    ' ~~ Check Control Point Number
    subReportProcess = Mid(ws.Range("I" & ind).Text, 12, 3)
    If subReportProcess = "201" Or subReportProcess = "202" Or subReportProcess = "203" Or subReportProcess = "204" Or subReportProcess = "205" Then
        brand = "PBS"
    Else
        brand = "SWG"
    End If
ElseIf reportProcess = "Revenue - GBS" Or reportProcess = "Revenue - GTS IS" Or reportProcess = "Fulfillment - Services(Operational)" Then
    brand = "PBS"
ElseIf reportProcess = "Revenue - TSS" Then
    brand = "TSS"
ElseIf reportProcess = "Accounts Receivable" Or reportProcess = "IBM Credit LLC - Accounts Receivable" Then
    brand = "AR"
End If

country = Trim(LTrim(RTrim(ws.Range("V" & ind).Text)))
If country = "Taiwan" Then
    geo = "Taiwan"
ElseIf country = "India" Then
    geo = "India"
ElseIf country = "New Zealand" Or country = "Australia" Then
    geo = "ANZ"
ElseIf country = "Hong Kong" Then
    geo = "Hong Kong"
ElseIf country = "Philippines" Or country = "Malaysia" Or country = "Singapore" Or country = "Thailand" Or country = "Vietnam" Or country = "Indonesia" Then
    geo = "ASEAN"
Else
    'Delete the row
    activecell.entirerow.delete
    ind = ind - 1
    goto GotoNextRecord
End If
ws.Range("B" & ind) = geo
ws.Range("A" & ind) = brand
    GotoNextRecord:
    Next ind
```